# Using knockout.js 3 with JSF 2.2

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, knockout.js, jsf-2.2

I'm currently investigating the user of knockoutjs with JSF 2.2 and have faced a few challenges. 
Background: I'm developing an application for a using JSF 2.2 as the view framework. This works for 90% of the pages in the application. There is a page or two where the users will undertake several operations on the client-side (hence the knockoutjs part) and it does not make sense to have several callbacks to the server (among the concerns is limited bandwidth in E. Africa) but rather keep everything client side and reflect incremental changes then save when they are done. 
Problem: To keep things specific, knockoutjs has worked to a point (for display of information) but it fails for input fields even though the "data-bind" attribute whoes up on the UI. To keep things concise I'll use a question object and the display of it's label for edit as an example;

My View Model for knockoutjs looks something like this;

```
function Question(question){
    var self = this;
    self.label = question.label; 
}
function QuestionViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var questionData = loadQuestions();//loads the list of questions from the sever
    self.questions = ko.observableArray();
    for(var i=0; i<questionData.questions.length; i++) {
        var question = questionData.questions[i];
        self.questions.push(new Question(question));
    }
    self.currentQuestion = ko.observable();
    self.selectQuestion = function(question){
        self.currentQuestion(question);
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new QuestionViewModel());
```

The JSF field that the question will be bound to is

```
<h:form>
<!-- .......other view stuff...... -->
    <h:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="60">
        <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-bind" value="value: currentQuestion().label"/>
    </h:inputTextarea>
<!-- ......more view stuff..... -->
</h:form>
```

And the final HTML that renders in the UI looks this

```
<textarea data-bind="value: currentQuestion().label" rows="5" cols="60" name="j_idt97">/textarea>
```

But when currentQuestion changed (the question number is bound to a label using the text binding and changes, do I know the question data is there, stepping through in firebug confirms this) nothing is displayed
I am at my wits end about this and I've been unable to find a similar question posted so I hope this leads to a fruitful discussion and a range of potential answers. Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough info here to answer your question, I don't think. If you post more of your view/jsf code, and your question object that would be helpful. Most helpful would be an example in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @scaryman. I would put the example in jsFiddle but it does not support JSF to my knowledge. Unfortunately I cannot include additional JSF view code at this time. I have added in the Question object as well as the code pertaining to the loading of said object via JSON. All of that works. It's the tying of an observable to an input field that's failing.

Comment: What's the value (as determined by `console.log` or the debugger) of `currentQuestion()` at the time the problem occurs? You mention the "question number" but I don't see any VM property corresponding to it. You're not storing the question number in `currentQuestion`, are you?

Comment: @Kenneth write the relevant bit of your markup in plain html then, it's possible that just the exercise will help you uncover a bug, and if it doesn't then we have a full example to look at and see what isn't quite right

Comment: @ebohlman, I trimmed the question number to keep it concise.

Comment: @scaryman thanks for the idea, I'll try that out and update the question if I find anything. For now I've gone another route in the interest of keeping time.

Comment: I suggest you define a global reference to your ViewModel, in order to follow and control the ViewModel state: `var window.VM = new QuestionViewModel(); ko.applyBindings(VM);`.

Then, later on, you can go to the console and do things like `VM.currentQuestion(VM.questions()[0])` which would affect the page in real time and allow you to have a more clear idea of what is (or else is *not*) going on. That would help you a lot while trying to figure out the interactions between the different observables.

Comment: Thanks  @BrancoMedeiros but I gave up and decided to go with a different technology.